# Serial port, WriteFile affects ReadFile

Tags: c, serial-port

I'm having a problem with the serial port code.

I just do:

```
opencomm(); 
send(); 
closecomm();
```

and the `ClearCommError() (inside recv())` returns in 
`comstat.cbInQue` the same amount that was sent.

So, if `sizeof (sendbuff)` is 100, 
I get 100 in `comstat.cbInQue`.

After reading one byte with `ReadFile`, `comstat.cbInQue` decrements (after subsequent `ClearCommError()`, of course).

The values read are not the ones that were written. 
There is no device connected to the port.

The strangest thing is **this code used to work**, but not anymore.

```
WORD sendbuff[128];
static HANDLE hComm; 

static void opencomm (void) 
{ 
    static COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0,0,0,0,0}; 

    static DCB dcb = { 
        sizeof (DCB),   //   DCBlength 
        115200, // * BaudRate 
        1,      //   fBinary 
        0,      // * fParity 
        0,      //   fOutxCtsFlow 
        0,      //   fOutxDsrFlow 
        0,      //   fDtrControl 
        0,      //   fDsrSensitivity 
        1,      //   fTXContinueOnXoff 
        0,      //   fOutX 
        0,      //   fInX 
        0,      //   fErrorChar 
        0,      //   fNull 
        0,      //   fRtsControl 
        0,      //   fAbortOnError 
        0,      //   fDummy2 
        0,      //   wReserved 
        8*k,    //   XonLim 
        2*k,    //   XoffLim 
        8,      // * ByteSize 
        0,      // * Parity 
        0,      // * StopBits 
        0,      //   XonChar 
        1,      //   XoffChar 
        0,      //   ErrorChar 
        0,      //   EofChar 
        0,      //   EvtChar 
        0       //   wReserved1 
    }; 

        hComm = CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); 
        if (hComm != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { 
            SetupComm(hComm, 16*k, 16*k); 
            SetCommState(hComm, &dcb); 
            SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts); 
        } 
} 

static void closecomm (void) 
{ 
        CloseHandle(hComm); 
} 

static BYTE recv (void) 
{ 
    BYTE text; 
    DWORD temp; 

    COMSTAT comstat; 

        while (1) { 
            ClearCommError(hComm, &temp, &comstat); 
            if (comstat.cbInQue != 0) break; 

            Sleep(1); 
        } 

        ReadFile(hComm, &text, 1, &temp, NULL); 

        return text; 
} 

static void send (void) 
{ 
    DWORD temp; 

        // send to other comp 
        WriteFile(hComm, sendbuff, sizeof (sendbuff), &temp, NULL); 

        // check other comp done 
        if (recv() != 0xAA) { 
            Beep(1000, 100); 
            quit(); // comm error 
        } 
}
```

Comment: For completeness, please include the **real** declaration of `sendbuff`, which by the looks of it, is somewhere above these functions in the same source file.

Comment: sendbuff added. People would probably complain about sendbuff not being initialized, thats why I haven't included it first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the cable. Not properly shielded and too long.